# add attribute to asp generated html elements - don't have code it was compiled from

Tags: asp.net, html

If I have two inputs in a file I've received which are "put together" with `aspx`

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name:" CssClass="login_label"></asp:Label></td>
    <td style="width: 200px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td style="width: 3px" align="left">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUserName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txtUserName">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password:" CssClass="login_label"></asp:Label></td>
    <td style="width: 200px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TabIndex="2" Width="200px" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
    <td style="width: 3px">
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ErrorMessage="Required">Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
</tr>
```

How can I add `autocapitalize="off"` attribute to the inputs? Whenever I try to add something to this code——well, most of the time——it just totally breaks. But I would like it to be usable on mobile devices. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can add `autocapitalize="off"`  to textboxes in .net 4 without problems. Additionally, you can add it via javascript as well.

Comment: @Candide But I don't have access to the original file this was created from in .net. Is there anyway I can add it to this line just by appending it to the end of the `<asp:...></asp:TextBox>` string? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Also, what do you mean, you don't have access to the code? Do the aspx pages have no code in them? You should add these details in the question.

Comment: @Candide well, I'm demonstrating that I don't have anything but the very smallest idea how asp works. I thought it was compiled from what Pow-lan referred to as "the code behind". That is, where I would type a command like `NameOfInput.Attributes.Add('autocapitalize','off')` and then it would be compiled into the lines of html with the `<asp:` elements above. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the code behind:

```
NameOfInput.Attributes.Add('autocapitalize','off')
```

that is how you add an attribute to an html element visible by the server.

javascript: be wary this may not work right in all versions of IE. This should be in the document load event

```
document.getElementById('<%txtUserName.ClientID%>').setAttribute('autocapitalize','off');
```

jQuery: same warning as above.
also this should be in $(docuemnt).ready() function or load event.

```
$('#<%txtUserName.ClientID%>').attr('autocapitalize','off');
```

see this question for a better reason why you can't do what  you want to here:

[Autocapitalize attribute on input element (used for iOS) breaks validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333416/autocapitalize-attribute-on-input-element-used-for-ios-breaks-validation)

one last edit:

Apparently from the IOS development docs there is an example where you can add the attribute to your form element.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DesigningForms/DesigningForms.html

So maybe you can add it to the form element, which is not an asp namespace control. the validator may cry but you might not get a compile error.

Comment: Thanks Pow-lan. If I don't have that code, how can I add the attribute in-line here?

Comment: I was just adding that when you added your comment

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it using jquery, but I'd rather just figure out what it looks like once .net compiles it into its code and just inline that if it's possible. .net applications seem always to be on the verge of collapsing under their own weight, and this one gave me an error when i just added jquery. Thanks again!

Comment: As far as I know you will get validation errors adding attributes to your asp:whatever element unless they are extended and defined. The only way to add them and not have the validator cry at you is to add them on the client side or add them in the code behind. Glad to help.